# ifelse, is.na and replace

Tags: r, if-statement, isnan

I have a big data frame where I am trying to figure out with NA values

| q3 | times_30 |
| --- | --- |
| Very easy | 18/11/2021 |
| Easy | 01/01/2021 |
| NA | Not due |
| NA | No answer |
| NA | 01/02/2021 |

I am using

```
df$q3<-ifelse (is.na(df$q3), df$times_30,df$q3)
```

Where gives me

| q3 | times_30 |
| --- | --- |
| Very easy | 18/11/2021 |
| Easy | 01/01/2021 |
| Not due | Not due |
| No answer | No answer |
| 01/02/2021 | 01/02/2021 |

but I would like instead of replaced with the date at the NA of q3 to give me a "No answer", as the following

| q3 | times_30 |
| --- | --- |
| Very easy | 18/11/2021 |
| Easy | 01/01/2021 |
| Not due | Not due |
| No answer | No answer |
| No answer | 01/02/2021 |

Answer (score 0):

You may try using `dplyr::case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(q3 = case_when(
    is.na(q3) & times_30 == "Not due" ~ times_30,
    is.na(q3) ~ "No answer",
    TRUE ~ q3
  ))

 

    q3   times_30
1 Very easy 18/11/2021
2      Easy 01/01/2021
3   Not due    Not due
4 No answer  No answer
5 No answer 01/02/2021
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: "x must be a character vector, not a `factor` object."  I tried to convert to character end run it again but it doesn't change anything

Comment: @Meli In your data, was both `q3` and `times_30` are character?

Comment: times_30 is character and q3 is a factor

Comment: @Meli Does it not works although you change both to character?